# Not able to open swagger documentation in gcp ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, flask-restplus

I have created a simple flask api with swagger integration using flask_restplus library. It is working fine in localhost. But when I use it in gcp kubernetes
ingress, it is giving results for endpoints but not able to show the documentation or swagger ui. Here are the browser console errors [browser console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPBeu.jpg)

Here is `ingress.yml` file

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-restplustest
  annotations:
    
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "web-static-ip"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /rt
        backend:
          serviceName: restplustest
          servicePort: 5000
```

In local system localhost:5000/rt shows the swagger-ui

Comment: did you test the container locally (not just the code)? This may be an issue with the container environment. What happens if you bypass the ingress, such as querying the pod from another pod? (Note, you won't get the UI but the application logs should show the js application loading, and you should get a proper 200 response)

Comment: yes container is working locally.

Comment: Can you try from another pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint return a script that references other scripts located on `/swaggerui/*` but that path is not defined in your Ingress.

It may be solved if you add that path to your service as well

```
  - path: /swaggerui/*
    backend:
      serviceName: restplustest
      servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: I tried it. It is saying no api definition provided

Comment: @Harhaaakr what error message or http status code did you get?

Comment: I tried /swaggerui/ and it is working thanks a lot!!